# Saving data of a table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 3 textfields, a submit button and a table view in a view controller. Now I want to show the datas of the 3 text fields to 3 labels of a custom cell in my table view and when I again update the datas the updated datas should be shown in the next cell. But in my code the updated datas are showing in the cells. The previous datas are overwriting. SO can any one tell me where am I wrong?

This is my ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *addressTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *phoneTextField;
- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *detailTable;

@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *arrPeopleDetail;


@end
```

This is my ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "detailObject.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end


@implementation ViewController
{
detailObject *peopleDetail;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.arrPeopleDetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
peopleDetail = [[detailObject alloc]init];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender {

[self.detailTable reloadData];


if ([self.nameTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [self.addressTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [self.phoneTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] ) {
    UIAlertView *alrt = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Plaeas Enter Text In The Empty Field" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil ];
    [alrt show];
}
else{

    peopleDetail.strPeopleName = self.nameTextField.text;
    peopleDetail.strPeopleAddress = self.addressTextField.text;
    peopleDetail.strPeoplePhoneNumber = self.phoneTextField.text;

    [self.arrPeopleDetail addObject:peopleDetail];


}

//[self.detailTable reloadData];


}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];

UILabel *lbl1 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
lbl1.text = [[self.arrPeopleDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"strPeopleName"];

UILabel *lbl2 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
lbl2.text = [[self.arrPeopleDetail        objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"strPeopleAddress"];

UILabel *lbl3 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
lbl3.text = [[self.arrPeopleDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"strPeoplePhoneNumber"];

return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return [self.arrPeopleDetail count];


}


@end
```

This is the .h NSObject class that I have Taken.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface detailObject : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *strPeopleName;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *strPeopleAddress;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *strPeoplePhoneNumber;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add line peopleDetail = [[detailObject alloc]init]; in else case of submitButton action and after adding the new object into array reload table view data

i.e.

else{

```
peopleDetail = [[detailObject alloc]init];
peopleDetail.strPeopleName = self.nameTextField.text;
peopleDetail.strPeopleAddress = self.addressTextField.text;
peopleDetail.strPeoplePhoneNumber = self.phoneTextField.text;

[self.arrPeopleDetail addObject:peopleDetail];
[self.detailTable reloadData];
```

}

You can remove the peopleDetail = [[detailObject alloc]init]; from viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

I realised where I was wrong. I was creating the object globally instead of creating it locally. If anyone does this mistake what happens is, every time when user enters data the datas are being overwritten because the created object is one. So the main mistake was creating the object globally instead of creating it locally.

So the updated ViewController.m is..

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "detailObject.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end


@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.arrPeopleDetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender {

if ([self.phoneTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] && [self.addressTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] && [self.phoneTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] ) {
    UIAlertView *alrt = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Fillup The Above Fields" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alrt show];
}

else if ([self.nameTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    UIAlertView *alrt_name = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Plaeas Enter Name" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil ];
    [alrt_name show];
}

else if ([self.addressTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *alrt_address = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Enter Address" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alrt_address show];
}
else if ([self.phoneTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *alrt_phoneNumber = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Enter Phone Number" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alrt_phoneNumber show];
}

else
{
    detailObject *peopleDetail = [[detailObject alloc] init];
    peopleDetail.strPeopleName = self.nameTextField.text;
    peopleDetail.strPeopleAddress = self.addressTextField.text;
    peopleDetail.strPeoplePhoneNumber = self.phoneTextField.text;

    [self.arrPeopleDetail addObject:peopleDetail];

    self.nameTextField.text = @"";
    self.addressTextField.text = @"";
    self.phoneTextField.text = @"";

}

[self.detailTable reloadData];


}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];


UILabel *lbl1 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
lbl1.text = [[self.arrPeopleDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"strPeopleName"];

UILabel *lbl2 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
lbl2.text = [[self.arrPeopleDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"strPeopleAddress"];

UILabel *lbl3 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
lbl3.text = [[self.arrPeopleDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"strPeoplePhoneNumber"];

return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return [self.arrPeopleDetail count];

}


@end
```